# Installing MongoDB Extension for usage in laravel does not work

Tags: php, mongodb

i installed the mongoDB extension in my php.ini aswell but it still gives the following error, can someone help?

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

 Problem 1
- mongodb/mongodb 1.1.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your syst
```

em.
         - mongodb/mongodb 1.1.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.2.0 -> the requested PHP        extension mongodb is missing from your syst
em.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.1.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your syst
em.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.5 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your syst
em.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.4 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your syst
em.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.3 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your syst
em.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your syst
em.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your syst
em.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your syst
em.
    - jenssegers/mongodb v3.2.0 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1
.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2].
    - Installation request for jenssegers/mongodb 3.2.* -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.2.0].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.5\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you did not have the correct MongoDB extension installed.

Depends on the OS your app is running, you can install MongoDB extension accordingly. http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.php